# Update partiion metadata in HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE table T1 with column C1 and C2 partitioned over C2. I want to change the data type of the column C1 from string to boolean. I used this query

```
ALTER TABLE T1 CHANGE C1 C1 boolean CASCADE;
```

Then I ran Insert OVERWRITE query to overwrite partition data. But it seems like for old partitions C1 is still string. For new partitions it is boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Partition is a physical folder in hdfs. So, c1 string folder will be there. Best idea will be -

Backup data original table.

Drop and re cecreate the table with new partition.

reload data from backup and drop backup table.